# FontAwesome Icon not changing in Scene builder

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, java-8, icons, scenebuilder

I want to use fontawsome icons in my project. I'm using JavaFx (java8) and the fontawesomefx-8.9 library. Unfortunately the icons don't change when I change them in the "Glyph Name" section of SceneBuilder.

I have integrated the fontawesomefx-8.9.jar into my project. After that I was able to use FontAwsomeIconView in sceneBuilder.

But unfortunately the default icon does not change if I select another icon.

**Main:**

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("freelancerdashboardgui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Freelancer Dashboar");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 875));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="756.0" prefWidth="1159.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" >
   <padding>
      <Insets left="50.0" />
   </padding>
   <VBox prefHeight="756.0" prefWidth="276.0" style="-fx-background-color: #202A2F;">
      <children>
         <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="276.0" stylesheets="@css/styling.css" text="Überblick" textFill="WHITE">
            <graphic>
               <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="GEAR" text="" />
            </graphic>
            <opaqueInsets>
               <Insets />
            </opaqueInsets>
            <padding>
               <Insets left="50.0" />
            </padding>
         </Button>
         <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="276.0" stylesheets="@css/styling.css" text="Kunde einpflegen" textFill="WHITE">
            <graphic>
               <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" text="" />
            </graphic>
            <opaqueInsets>
               <Insets />
            </opaqueInsets>
            <padding>
               <Insets left="50.0" />
            </padding>
         </Button>
         <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="276.0" stylesheets="@css/styling.css" text="Kunden" textFill="WHITE">
            <graphic>
               <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" text="" />
            </graphic>
            <opaqueInsets>
               <Insets />
            </opaqueInsets>
            <padding>
               <Insets left="50.0" />
            </padding>
         </Button>
         <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="276.0" stylesheets="@css/styling.css" text="Einstellungen" textFill="WHITE">
            <graphic>
               <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="address-card" text="" />
            </graphic>
            <opaqueInsets>
               <Insets />
            </opaqueInsets>
            <padding>
               <Insets left="50.0" />
            </padding>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image: No changes in after Change Glyph Name]

Does anyone know this case or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I see that you are using the embedded Scene Builder version from IntelliJ. Have you tried the standalone version [8.5.0](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download)?

Comment: yeah, i did, same problem

Comment: Try FontAwesomeFX 8.15

Comment: I'm curious, have you tried compiling and running this in an IDE? I've had some issues where Scenebuilder (Java 8,unsure of the exact version) did not interpret CSS as I expected it to but when I ran my project in eclipse it looked as it should. I have not have any issues with FontAwesome though, but I'm curious to see if this is a similar case

Comment: @Hubi: have you been able to fix this by now? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Luk, sry, no i did not. but you can let me know when you have solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Bro just empty the text field and it will work i've had the same problem.

Comment: Hi Said, I suggest you to add this as a comment, or add more information on code about how your answer could be a good approach to the question.